# Какое предложение из двух правильное?

Tags: синтаксис

Какое предложение правильное?

Тёмная материя – это вид гипотетической материи, испускающий электромагнитное излучение, но не взаимодействующий с ним.
**или**
Тёмная материя – это вид гипотетической материи, испускающей электромагнитное излучение, но не взаимодействующей с ним.

Comment: Если ответить на вопрос "Что не так в предложении?" чисто формально, то ответ будет таким: главная проблема в том, что это фотография, а не текст. Мне кажется, что Вам имеет смысл преобразовать это предложение в текстовую форму, если это, конечно, не домашнее задание, которые мы можем проверить (если Вы сами предложите варианты ответа), но не можем сами сделать за Вас.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант редактирования:

**Тёмная материя – это гипотетическая форма (вид)  материи, не испускающЕЙ электромагнитное излучение и напрямую не взаимодействующЕЙ с ним.**

О темной материи:

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тёмная_материя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)

https://ribalych.ru/2014/06/25/chto-takoe-tyomnaya-materiya/